# How can I establish trust in a X.509 certificate issued by an intermediary?

Tags: java, security

I have an XML document that is digitally signed. I use the XML Digital Signature API to verify the signature. But this document is a SAML 2.0 Assertion that will be used for single sign-on into our web application. As such I need to establish trust in the X.509 certificate used to sign the XML document.

The code I am using to try and establish this trust is:

```
String filename = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String password = "changeit";
keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keystore);
params.setRevocationEnabled(false);

CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
CertPath certPath = certFactory.generateCertPath(Arrays.asList(signatureCertificate));

CertPathValidator certPathValidator = CertPathValidator.getInstance(CertPathValidator.getDefaultType());
CertPathValidatorResult result = certPathValidator.validate(certPath, params);

PKIXCertPathValidatorResult pkixResult = (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult) result;
TrustAnchor ta = pkixResult.getTrustAnchor();
X509Certificate cert = ta.getTrustedCert();
```

When run the call to `certPathValidator.validate()` throws a `CertPathValidatorException` with the message `Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors`.

Examining the certificate, it says it has been issued by `OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign,OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3,OU=VeriSign\, Inc.,O=VeriSign Trust Network`.
This is not one of the trust anchors in the JDK's cacerts key store.

However, using IE to inspect a similar certificate's trust chain I see that `www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.`'s was issued by `VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary CA`, which does appear to be one of the trust anchors in the JDK's cacerts key store.

My question: how can I get Java to validate this certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the public cert of the issuing CA into the cacert keystore.

edit:  You can use keytool or one of the other tools out there.  Article describes keytool use: [keytool-Key and Certificate Management Tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. This may be a silly question, but how can I get the issuer's X.509 certificate?

Comment: http://www.verisign.com/support/roots.html - just below the registration form is a link to download all of Verisigns root certs.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. The certificate I needed wasn't on that site, but I was able to find it using Google. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you give a "for dummies" explanation of how to obtain the public cert of the issuing CA? I am working with the certificate at https://www.envmgr.com/LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx 
I've downloaded it to my pc and confirmed that it throws the "does not chain" error in Jdk1.7, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what xelco said - add the intermediate CA:

```
OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign,OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3,OU=VeriSign\, Inc.,O=VeriSign Trust Network
```

To the JDK's key store.  You can use keytool to do it.

Reason:  Generally when an XML message is signed, the signature includes only the signing cert.  X509 Certificates are like singly linked lists.  The End Entity points to its issuer.  The issuer points to its issuer until you get to a self-signed Root CA, which points to itself.  To verify a certificate according to PKIX, the validator needs to be able to build the whole CA chain from end entity to self signed root, so every part of the chain (except for the end entity) must be in your certificate store.

Answer (score -1):

I've got better solution. I've found java service that can be run and do everything for us.

Java:
http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java

Comment: code example please otherwise not helpful. and double check that this has been asked for.